# How to build one module into another module of same project in maven using in pom.xml

Tags: maven

I have a maven project which contains two modules.

module-1
module-2.

How can i build the module-2 by adding dependency in module-1's pom.xml.
Finally when the build is done, the module-1.jar contains files of module-1 also.

thanks in advance,
Ubedulla.

Answer (score 1):

The best sturcture for such project is like this:

```
  +-- pom.xml (root)
       +--- module-1
       !       +--- pom.xml
       +--- module-2
               +--- pom.xml
```

So the root pom contains the modules definition like this:

```xml
 <project ..>

 <groupId>groupId<groupId>
 <artifactId>the-root</artifactId>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>

 ...
 <modules>
   <module>module-1</module>
   <module>module-2</module>
 </modules>
```

So a module like module-1 look like this:

```xml
 <project ..>

 <parent>     
   <groupId>groupId<groupId>
   <artifactId>the-root</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>

 <artifactId>module-1</artifactId>
 ...
```

And module-2 look like this:

```xml
 <project ..>

 <parent>     
   <groupId>groupId<groupId>
   <artifactId>the-root</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>

 <artifactId>module-2</artifactId>
 ...
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>${project.groupId}<groupId>
     <artifactId>module-1</artifactId>
     <version>${project.version}</version>
   </dependency>
```

If you follow the best practice you don't need entries like `../module-1` etc.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways (assuming modules are jar projects):

1. Create a parent maven pom project
2. Create 1st jar maven project (module 1)
3. Create 2nd jar maven project(module 2) having module-1 as dependency in its pom.

Then you add in the parent project inside its pom the modules in this manner:

```
.....
<modules>
  <module>../module-1</module>
  <module>../module-2</module>
</modules>
......
```

In this case module-1 and module-2 artifactId.
Then all you need is to install the parent project using maven and all the rest will be created.